# Orchard: Welding a ContentPart to all ContentTypes

Tags: orchardcms

I have a requirement where i need to weld a ContentPart to all the content types. Please guide me what is the best place to write this code.

I looked into the Orchard source code where InfosetPart is being welded with all content types in ContentHandlerBase's Activating method.

Following the InfosetPart weld mechanism i created one class inheriting from ContentHandlerBase and in Activating method i placed a break point with following condition which is getting hit again and again (more than once for one content type)
    context.ContentType == "Page"

I'm not sure if it should be as it is because ideally it should hit this condition only once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you are implementing it is correct. Your code is executed multiple times because content handlers are invoked for each content item, and not just for the content type. This also allows you to weld your part to only some of you content items, not all items of a specified type.

You wrote that you created a subclass of `ContentHandlerBase`. You should use `ContentHandler` as a base class.

Below is a simple code example how this should be done.

```
public class MyPartHandler : ContentHandler 
{
    protected override void Activating(ActivatingContentContext context) {
        context.Builder.Weld<MyPart>();
    }
}
```